# Interface implementation in Go runtime

Tags: go

I'm reading a book about Go. In the interfaces chapter i found this statement:

> In the Go runtime, interface are implemented as a pair of pointers, one to the underlying type and one to the underlying value.

Can someone explain me these words with a concrete example?

Comment: There's not a "concrete example" to offer for language internals; you'd never access the pointers internal to an interface value. There are many posts out there explaining how interface values work, this one is pretty detailed and was my first result on Google: https://www.tapirgames.com/blog/golang-interface-implementation

Comment: The “pair of pointers” isn’t even necessarily true, that fact has changed a couple times over the years. The concepts all remain the same, an interface contains a dynamic type and value.

Answer (score 4):

This has pictures! Russ is the author of the initial Go gc compiler interface implementation. There have been a few minor revisions.

> [Go Data Structures: Interfaces](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces)
> Russ Cox
>
> This post is my take on the implementation of interface values in the “gc” compilers. This post has pictures.

---

For [Go source code](https://github.com/golang/go) see `go/src/runtime/iface.go`.